# Parking Detection on Raspberry Pi and decision making?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi, iot

**Dears,**

It's an honor to be on this programming-heaven of a platform! Thank you so much StackOverflowers for what you've done to us college students and programming noobies :D, anyway:

I'm taking an IoT course, and currently working on the final capstone. My idea that I chose was a camera-based parking system that detects availability using image-recognition. Tools provided to us were: Raspberry Pi 3, and a raspberry pi camera module.

So the camera should take a picture every 5 seconds and save it in a specific folder, a python code should process the image and give a boolean result for each parking spot and send it to MySQL database. Finally, this boolean results will be retrieved by a web-page and upon this info, the results should be shown on a virtual parking map for each parking spot.

What we reached right now is:
1- A python script that allows the camera to take a picture and save it in a specific folder.
2- A webpage that call on the MySQL database and get results for 20 parking lots (Parking lot number and status) and show them (in a very elegant way) on a parking scheme.

Our issue with the image processing part (which is basically 90% of the project :D). I've looked up github codes that allow me "using openCV" to process a specific photo and show images on X server, but I don't need that! I need to grap the info shown on the X server (whether the parking is green or red) and send this info for each parking lot to the MySQL database.

So my question is: are you guys familiar with any that somehow close enough to this idea, so I can start with it and edit the script to satisfy my need and specific photo that I captured using my RPi Camera? Please help me out, because i'm starting to panic tbh ':D.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are u able to detect parking? or you just need to decide parking is green or red?

Comment: Hello Yunus! Thank you for your time. Unfortunately no, I haven’t been able to detect the parking status and I frankly don’t know where to begin or where to look